# laravel checking if object is instance of

Tags: php, laravel

I have two objects, `trainee` and `instructor` which is inherited from `people` object. `people` has relation to `role`, but role is only for `people` although in fact this role is also inherited to `trainee` and `instructor` (value for `role_id` is empty for both objects).

in the people view i fetch all row, including rows from trainee and instructor. the code is error.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Role</label>
    <div class="controls">
        {{ Form::select('role_id', $roles, $person->role->id, array('class'=>'select2', 'data-placeholder'=>'Pilih Role')) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

is there any way to check wich instance `$person` is, is it people, trainee/instuctor. that way if person is trainee/instructor then dont display role dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If  role is empty or NULL for both `trainee` and `instructor`, a conditional check for `$person->role` should work

```
      @if($person->role)
         <label for="" class="control-label">Role</label>
         <div class="controls">
               {{ Form::select('role_id', $roles, $person->role->id, array('class'=>'select2', 'data-placeholder'=>'Pilih Role')) }}
         </div>
      @endif
```

Comment: I already did that, is it the only way of doing this, also if this is faster then i will stick with it.

Comment: Based on your question specifics, yes, what you did would be simplest. I'm assuming right now that `instructor` and `trainee` are both eloquent models. I'm curious did you use single table inheritance (something like http://www.colorfultyping.com/single-table-inheritance-in-laravel-4/) or do you have separate person, instructor and trainee tables?